# Get the image path

Tags: services

may be this question has been asked earlier but i have not found an appropriate answer for this. I have image uri path and i want to create a web services in drupal. From android when i call this webservices i will send the uri then i want to get the image url that will return me my custom image style url. But when i am passing the url with file extension giving me `Could not find the Controller`.this is servieces_resources function

```
'image_url' => array('operations' => array('retrieve' => array(
  'help' => t('The resource to retrive the image of the given url/uri.'),
  'callback' => '_fieldinsync_image_url_retrieve',
  'args' => array(
      array(
            'name' => 'url',
            'optional' => FALSE,
            'source' => array('path' => 'url'),
            'type' => 'string',
            'description' => 'The url/uri of the image.',
     )),
  'access callback' => 'services_access_menu',
),),),
```

This is my function that will return the url of the image::

```
function _fieldinsync_image_url_retrieve($imgUrl){
 $value;
 $value[]=array(
 'vname'=> 'session_id',
 'sname' => 'session_name');
 $value['uri'] = image_style_url('mobile_product_image', $imgUrl);
  return $value;
  }
```

Uri is :`public://Tab - A2107.jpg`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. *"This is my function that will return the url of the image"* - what you pasted is not a function, and no `return` in that snippet. I guess it's meant to be a part of `hook_menu` or something like that - if so, wrap it into minimal implementation that works. And tell us your Drupal version. Also, it's a common courtesy to use [Drupal coding standards](https://drupal.org/coding-standards).

Comment: now please check it

Comment: can u tell me what is $imgUrl exactlly???

Comment: @zhilevan $imgUrl is: public://Picture1.png

Answer (score 1):

I take your problem is converting a URI like public://filename.extension in a URL that can be used outside Drupal. That can be accomplished replacing the call to `image_style_url('mobile_product_image', $imgUrl)` with the following code.

```
$uri = image_style_url('mobile_product_image', $imgUrl);
$obj = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri);
$value['uri'] = $obj->getExternalUrl();
```

Comment: Can you check it my this code is perfect:
'image_url' => array('operations' => array('retrieve' => array(
  'help' => t('The resource to retrive the image of the given url/uri.'),
  'callback' => '_fieldinsync_image_url_retrieve',
  'args' => array(
      array(
            'name' => 'url',
            'optional' => FALSE,
            'source' => array('path' => 'url'),
            'type' => 'string',
            'description' => 'The url/uri of the image.',
     )),
  'access callback' => 'services_access_menu',
),),),

Comment: It answers the question's title, but not *Could not find the Controller* error OP asks in question's body...

Comment: My url is :
http://localhost/sitename/bservices/image_url/public://Picture1.png.json

hTTP Method is GET and 404 Could not find the Controller

Comment: But this Url is working
http://localhost/sitename/bservices/image_url/Picture1.png.json

Here i want to send "public://Picture1.png" inplace of "Picture1.png"

Comment: got my Answer feeling very Happy.

needs to add these lines in settings.php

$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;